# Python - Creating a list of files in a given directory, non-recursively

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, unix, os.path

I'm experiencing difficulty with something that should be so simple -
 creating a list out of the files in a given directory path. I suspect the issue has to do with relative paths but still cannot get it to work properly. Here's a starting point:

```
 import sys, os.path

 dir = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
 print(f'Given directory path: {dir}')

 filelist = []
 [filelist.append(os.path.abspath(item)) for item in os.listdir(dir)
     if os.path.isfile(item) if not item.startswith('.')]

 for file in filelist:
     print(file)
```

- Files only. No subdirectories added to the list.
- List entries should include the full pathname to the file.
- Non-recursive. Only the files in the given folder.
- Skip hidden files.
- Using os.walk (recursive) and deleting list entries is considered a hacky solution.

---

### Update

The issue was related to os.listdir and relative paths, and that my awkward list comprehension unnecessarily increased the complexity of the composition. Fixing the list comprehension as suggested in the comments made it more clear and easier to put it all together, and it works as it should now. Working code below:

```
filelist = [os.path.join(os.path.abspath(dir),file)
            for file in os.listdir(dir)
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir,file))
            if not file.startswith('.')]
```

**Update 2:** Free from my self-imposed list comprehension prison, I realize it is possible to use next and os.walk, too:

```
filelist = [os.path.join(dir,file)
            for file in next(os.walk(dir))[2]
            if not file.startswith('.')]
```

Comment: what's wrong with simply using `os.listdir`?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: If you mean using os.listdir without os.isfile, it will also append the subdir names to the list

Comment: what are you doing with your list comprehension? shoudln't you be removing `[]`

Comment: The error I'm getting is that the file paths in the resulting file list point to the directory containing the script instead of where the file is located (in sys.argv[1]). I believe it's due to the relative path not being passed along somewhere. There's also another error that occurs for certain directories (containing several files) where only one file will get added to the list and I have no idea why.

Comment: What's wrong with the list comprehension? Please elaborate.

Comment: you need to get the path where you are running the script from if you need relative path added `os.getcwd` will give you the current working dir.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mixing up the terminology. I meant that the resulting file list doesn't show the correct path to the files.

Comment: The list comprehension looks crazy.  Either you want `filelist = [os.path.abspath(item) for item in ...]` or else `filelist = []; for item in ..: filelist.append(os.path.abspath(item))` but you have an unholy mixture of append inside a comprehension.

Comment: @tripleee noted, thanks. Is it preferred using list comprehension for this or a for loop, and why?

Comment: I would perhaps recommend a `for` loop in this case just because the list comprehension looks kind of complex, but I don't think there is the case for a strong recommendation either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that os.path.abspath(item), where item is in dir, must assume that item is in the current working directory because os.listdir only returns the objects relative to the dir argument.  Instead use
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,item)) or maybe just os.path.join(dir,item)

Comment: I had previously attempted this but must've messed it up due to my wacky list comprehension unnecessarily increasing the complexity of the composition. Fixing the list comprehension as suggested in the comments made it more clear and easier to put it all together, and it works as it should now. Will update my question with the correct code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think glob will exclude hidden files. This should give you a listing of the files at the path provided.

```
from os.path import abspath, isfile, join
from  glob import glob

files = [abspath(x) for x in glob(join(sys.argv[1], '*')) if isfile(x)]
```

Comment: Thanks, glob does seem to do the trick. However, I can't believe this operation cannot be done with os, does a simple procedure like this really require importing another module? There's much more to my script and this would be the only place glob is used.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's a problem =/ Why would you have concerns about importing glob and using it once?

Comment: I assumed it's good practice to try to keep things as light as possible and not import more than necessary. I already use os in various places in the script for other operations and I guess it's a bit of a letdown that os can't be used here as well, for something that should be so simple